# how to pass column of array to Object field from an Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Below is my code, I'm trying to pass the values from the 'dataList' to this.data object 'labels', 'datasets'-> data;

but i'm getting undefined result if create a variable and store values and then pass it to lables, data.

Here my question is how set values for labels, data from dataList array.

```
    this.dataList = [['lable1', 200], ['lable2', 300], ['lable3', 500]];
```

> //now I want to access all labels to label, all numbers to data in
>   below instead of static data i want to put data from dataList

```
    this.data = {
    labels: ['label1', label2, labels3],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [200, 300, 500],
        backgroundColor: [
          "#FF6384",
          "#36A2EB",
          "#FFCE56"
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
          "#FF6384",
          "#36A2EB",
          "#FFCE56"
        ]
      }]
  };
```

instead of static values in labels, data I want to put dynamic data that is in dataList.

Comment: Your `getEncounterDashBoard()` is an asynchronous method. Instead assign your `this.data.labels` inside your `subscribe` callback.

Comment: that is okay my Friend, I'm storing data in this.datalist it has the all values. I want to store one of the column from datalist and that should be in labels, and another is in data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use JavaScript's [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to get working.

> [Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-reduce-inner-list) - you can edit `this.dataList` variable to see the output changing dynamical

```
this.dataList = [['lable1', 200], ['lable2', 300], ['lable3', 500]];

this.data = {
  labels: this.dataList.reduce((result, item) => {
    result.push(item[0]);
    return result;
  }, []),
  datasets: [
    {
      data: this.dataList.reduce((result, item) => {
        result.push(item[1]);
        return result;
      }, []),
      backgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56"
      ]
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `labels` have the same elements as `dataList`:

```
labels: dataList,
```

If you want to avoid mutations:

```
labels: dataList.slice(),
```

Or:

```
labels: [...dataList],
```

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for your reply, I have two columns in 'dataList' and I want to store all first column data in Labels, and the second one will be in data.

Comment: Then do `labels: dataList[0]`.

Comment: I belive you meant labels: this.dataList[0]. this is giving me an typeError.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code in the .subscribe() function block, because it is asynchronous and you will need to wait for the data to be returned. Then, just assign to variables labels and datasets. I used es6 here, but you don't need to.

```
dataList: Array<any> = [];
data: any = {}; //give data an inital value
searchCond: SearchConditions;

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {

this.searchCond = new SearchConditions();
this.searchCond.eventType = "encounterType";

this.apiService.getEncounterDashBoard(this.searchCond)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.dataList = data.result;
    let [labels, datasets] = this.dataList; 
    this.data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets,
    };
  });
```

Comment: I tried that already, If I kept it inside .subscribe it will give cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined error.

Comment: @HariU Give data an inital value of {}, then you should not get this error. Take note, because subscribe function will only run after fetching the data, any function that needs to use dataList will need to be called from inside the subscribe function. I have updated my answer

Comment: in the Label and Data i want to store one of Column from the dataList in each. suppose I have two columns in dataList. first column data should be store in labels as showed already as static data, and the second column will be for Data. at last my output should be like static data which i have mentioned above. In your  way its not showing values.

Comment: ok, can you update your question to show the structure of `dataList`?

Comment: I Just updated and edited the code for your better understand.